# Using an ssh key with composer for a private vcs

Tags: php, git, composer-php, bitbucket

I'm trying to pull a private package hosted on Bitbucket into my project but I can't seem to get composer to work correctly with my SSH key.

I'm currently trying:

```
{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packagist.org"
},
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:{projectName}/{repo}.git",
    "ssh2": {
        "username": "git",
        "privkey_file": "/home/vagrant/.ssh/bitbucket_id_rsa",
        "pubkey_file": "/home/vagrant/.ssh/bitbucket_id_rsa.pub"
    }
},
```

When I try to run composer update I get `Permission denied (publickey)` but when I run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org -i /home/vagrant/.ssh/bitbucket_id_rsa` I can connect successfully.

I'm not sure if its even attempting to use the key specified because if I type random letters in the `priv` and `pub` key options, it still fails in the same way instead of throwing a file not found.

Hoping its just a small configuration error I've made as I'm not too sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: And without the username? Would it work?

Answer (score 6):

Tested with composer `2.0.8`, and the `ssh2` option is only supported for `"type": "composer"` (not yet for `git` nor for `vcs` type).

But even for `"composer"` type, you should write the `ssh2` options where they belong. Those belong inside the `options` key's object. E.g.:

```
{
  "repositories": [{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "ssh2.sftp://example.org",
    "options": {
      "ssh2": {
        "username": "composer",
        "pubkey_file": "/home/composer/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
        "privkey_file": "/home/composer/.ssh/id_rsa"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Located where they are, it's not a big surprise composer is simply ignoring those settings.

### Other alternatives

If you have a private bitbucket repo, you should probably use [the bitbucket driver](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#bitbucket-driver-configuration):

```
{
    "config": {
        "bitbucket-oauth": {
            "bitbucket.org": {
                "consumer-key": "myKey", 
                "consumer-secret": "mySecret"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Last but not least, in a `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file we can instead of said options-key do:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -p 22 -i '$(pwd)/my-ssh-key.txt' -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -F /dev/null"
```

> Where `my-ssh-key.txt` file's content is set to be used as ssh-key.
>
> As long as above runs on a Docker-image it just works, but for a so-called "Runner", we need to undo above, like:
>
> ```
> git config --global --unset core.sshCommand
> ```

Comment: Do I need to add options for each repository?